# What is this function doing? i'm most confused with the Read and write part

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know this is a constructor function but it i don't get the read and write part.. i know it has an if and else statement but i'm confused with what it doing!

```
 self.CondInspecChks_RevValve_UI = ko.computed({      
         read: function () {
             return self.CondInspecChks_RevValve() == 1 ? true : false;
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            self.CondInspecChks_RevValve(newValue ? 1 : 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: [Writable computed observables](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html)

Comment: Besides the point, but FWIW, `? true : false` is completely redundant and superfluous…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Knockout computed observable](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) - it allows a dynamic value to be assigned to a [KO observable](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

```js
const normalObservable = ko.observable("hello");
const computedObservable = ko.computed(function() {
  return "my dynamic value is: " + normalObservable();
})

console.log(normalObservable())
console.log(computedObservable())

//update the observable
normalObservable("world");

console.log(normalObservable())

//the computed also changed
console.log(computedObservable())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

In this particular case, this is using advanced construction of the computed to make it a [writeable computed](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html).

```js
const someWriteableValue = ko.observable("hello")

const computed = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return "my dynamic value is: " + someWriteableValue();
    },
    write: function (value) {
       someWriteableValue(value);
    }
})

console.log(computed());

//update the computed
computed("world");

console.log(computed());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a knockoutjs [computed observable which is writable](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html).

It relies on there being an underlying observable property called `CondInspecChks_RevValve` which is numeric (1 or 0), and the observable in the question `CondInspecChks_RevValve_UI` returns `true` or `false` and allows you to write to it too, which will update the underlying property as appropriate.